# Autoionization state

Tags: electronic-configuration

I am reading this paper:
"[Role of Autoionizing State in Resonant High-Order Harmonic Generation and Attosecond Pulse Production](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.123901)"

In the paper a transition from the $\ce{In+}$ ground state to an autoionization state is discussed:

$$4d^{10}5s^2 \, {}^1\!S_0 \longrightarrow 4d^95s^25p\,(^2\!D)\,{}^1\!P_1$$

I am trying to understand why this is an autoionization state.
If I follow the Aufbau principle, an electron in the ground state $4d^{10}5s^2$ that is excited should be in the state $3d^95s^25p$.
If this is just the lowest excited state, why is it considered an autoionization state?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Please note $\LaTeX$ is preferred over images when reasonable.